# Alignment issue with multiple divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

Im using a search form that contains a text box and submit button...For some reason, I have a alignment issue with the 2 elements(input=text and button on the top of the div) particularly in chrome..

Can you please let me know what is the issue?

HTML & CSS

```
  <form id="bigsearchform_new" method="post" >
      <input id="search_string" name="search_string" type="text" class="startnewsearch rounded" placeholder="Search..." maxlength="500" /><input id="bigsearchbutton_new"  type="button" class="searchButton" title="Click here to search the database"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="antiCSRF" value="{{acsrf}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="{{session_id}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="commodity_id" id="commodity_id" />
  </form>

        </div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EPyEe/)

Answer (score 2):

Input elements are vertically misaligned as they have inline layout and different heights. One of the options is to use `vertical-align` property with `middle/bottom/top` (for example) value :

```
input {
   vertical-align : middle;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EPyEe/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your button is missing the `value` property:

```
<input id="bigsearchbutton_new"
       type="button" 
       class="searchButton" 
       title="Click here to search the database" 
       value="Go" />
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPyEe/1/)